# not able to import python module despite setting PYTHONPATH

Tags: macos, python-2.7, core-foundation

I am trying to concatenate some pdf files from the command line on mac.

After reading online I found there is a python script for this located here:

```
/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py
```

After resetting my python to be the system's 2.7 python (`sudo port select --set python python27`), I get this error when trying to run the above script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py", line 23, in <module>
from CoreFoundation import *
ImportError: No module named CoreFoundation
```

So apparently python is not able to import something called `CoreFoundation`. Looking, I find said `CoreFoundation.py` at this place on my file system:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/Carbon/CoreFoundation.py
```

And, indeed, inspecting the `sys.path` variable seems to indicate that the above directory is somehow overlooked:

```
$ python
>>> import.sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

(Pardon the long unbroken line. The point is, things like

'/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages'

are found in `sys.path`, but the arefore-mentioned

'/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/Carbon'

is not.) So I try to manually add to PYTHONPATH (which was previously empty):

PYTHONPATH="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/Carbon"

...but even after doing this, I get the same `ImportError: No module named CoreFoundation` error.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have to do this from the command line? The is a free app, PDFsam, that does what you want?

Comment: Yes of course there's online utlities. And the original task I wanted to carry out is dead and gone. But as a developer, I want to grow and know how to fix things for the next time they go wrong.